# war game to_s method throws undefined method error

Tags: ruby

I have tried to debug this problem and I can't figure it out. I have a war card class and what I want to do is print the results showing the number of plays, number of count, and the hand both players had. I get number count and the players hand to work but I can't get number of plays. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The variable I am focused on is @num_plays.

Here I initialize num_plays and set it to 0
    class War

```
attr_reader :num_plays

def initialize

orig_deck = Deck.new
@player_a = DownStack.new
@player_b = DownStack.new
@limbo_stack = DownStack.new
@num_plays = 0
```

Here every time a player draws a card add to the value( I did not show all of play method)

```
def play
#Player Draw
@num_plays += 1
card_a = @player_a.deal
```

lastly my to_s method which throws a undefined method error.

```
def to_s 
        output = " "
    output +=  "Number of plays:" + " " + @player_a.num_plays.to_s
```

Comment: I see `num_plays` accessor on `War`, but you're calling it on `@player_a` -- is there one there, too? Please add the text of your error, too, please.

Comment: no I am not the idea was to add one to the count after every play

Comment: Here is the error: war.rb:99:in `to_s': undefined method `num_plays' for #<DownStack:0x2cc93a0> (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:4:in `write'
        from test.rb:4:in `print'
        from test.rb:4:in `<main>'

Comment: Not entirely sure what your trying to do, but your primary problem seems to be that you are trying to call `num_plays` on an object that doesn't have that as a method/attribute.

Comment: Add the error to your question by re-editing and appending it. Be sure to format it so it's readable.

Comment: Further to @JTG's comment, this cannot be answered without knowing, at minimum, whether `DownStack` has a method `num_plays` or instance variable `@num_plays` with an accessor. Whenever your question involves an exception that was raised, always give the full error message (less the stack trace, if that's obvious) and the line on which it was raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JTG suggested in the comments, the error is telling you that you're trying to call `num_plays` on a `DownStack` instance -- `@player_a.num_plays` in the code you've shown -- which doesn't implement it.

Using `num_plays` on the `War` instance, this should do what you've shown

```
# war.rb
def to_s
    "Number of plays: #{@num_plays}"
end
```

(*i.e.*, you need to add the other values you mentioned)